# Not able to find XSL Style Sheet folder inside Style Library folder in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, style-library

I am not able to find "XSL Style Sheet" folder inside "Style Library" folder in SharePoint Foundation 2010. 
The "Style Library" folder has only one file "Forms".

Comment: What XSL file are you looking for? Some files like blog.xsl which controls the render of posts in Blog sites only live in the file system under 14\TEMPLATE\XSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that is explained by the fact the XSL Style sheet is used by Web parts (Content Query Web Part, Table of Contents, Summary Links) available only on the Standard or Enterprise editions, in the Publishing Sites.

SharePoint Foundations does not support Publishing sites.

Comment: Thanks.Is there any way to get content query web part through SharePoint Designer?